# C#-Warning 2 Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Tags: c#, session

```
if ((Session["UserName"] != null && Session["LoginType"] == "Admin") || (Session["UserName"] != null && Session["LoginType"] == "Employee"))
{ 
    TotalMarketBalance();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to change the `if`-statement to this:

```
if (Session["UserName"] != null && 
     (Session["LoginType"] as string == "Admin" || 
      Session["LoginType"] as string == "Employee")
   )
```

`Session[string key]` returns an `object`. And if you compare an `object` to something using `==`, you do a *reference comparison*. And the string literal (`"Admin"` for example) will never have the same reference like that object, even if this object *is* a string.

By casting the `object` into a `string`, the compiler knows that it has to call the equality methods of `string`, which compare the string's contents instead of their references.

Of course you can do a direct cast (`(string)Session["LoginType"]`) or call `ToString()`, too. But the first will throw an exception if (for some strange reason) the return object is *not* a string. The second will throw a `NullReferenceException` if (for some strange reason) the value is still `null`.

Comment: Session["UserName"] != null = true but  (Session["LoginType"] as string == "Admin" || 
      Session["LoginType"] as string == "Employee") does not show true or false

Comment: @Dayanand Why not? What else would it show? Did you try it?

Comment: ya. working correctly. but when i keep mouse pointer on == sign at debug time. it not show true or false. why...

Answer (score 0):

Change `Session["LoginType"]` to `Session["LoginType"].ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

you can also cast to string:

```
(string)Session["LoginType"] == "Admin"
```

This is how the example is done in the Documentation [Reading Values From Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287606%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: FYI, that link is applicable to VS2003 and states "The document is archived and information here might be outdated". While it is correct and valid, please do not link to documents that are not current.

Comment: Session["UserName"] != null = true    but (string)Session["LoginType"].ToString() == "Employee") does not show true or false